# Jade's express template engine vs grunt-contrib-jade?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

This maybe a silly question, leading out of my lack of knowledge on this topic. So, please pardon me if it is indeed silly.

I am using a standard MEAN (Mongo, Express, Angular, Node) stack to develop a web application. In the Express configuration I am setting the template engine like so:

```
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
```

Now, the way this works is that Express takes care of rendering the jade as HTML in the browser. All nice and neat.

But, I see that many developers use a grunt module called grunt-contrib-jade to convert jade files to html. Is there any benefit of doing this in the previously mentioned setup where I leave it to express to do the pre-processing? Are there any advantages of one approach versus the other?

Answer (score 1):

when you render jade files on each request it's slower than serving a static HTML file.

But you can also cache jade files with express: http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app-settings

> view cache Enables view template compilation caching, enabled in production by default

There is another solution: compile jade files to JavaScript, serve them as static files and execute / render it on the client.

When compiling Jade to HTML, usually you cannot handle placeholders in the template, but I don't know how grunt-contrib-jade works.